# unable to customize tableView for side menu in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to add spacing between rows and set the header
here my code is -

```
    @IBOutlet weak var sideMenu: UITableView!
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TownTalkTableViewCell
         cell.logo.setImage(arr[indexPath.row]["icon"] as? UIImage, for: .normal)
        cell.grupName.text = array[indexPath.row]["groupname"] as? String

     return cell
```

Answer (score 1):

**First Add tableview Delegate and Data Source for both tableview in storyboard by taping control+draging into viewcontroller**

[image]
Then use the same delegate function to access sidemenu tableview.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var sideMenu: UITableView!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableview == sideMenu{
        return 2
    }else{
        //this is for tableView
        return 3
    }
}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableview == sideMenu{
            //use slide menu tableview cell
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TownTalkTableViewCell
            cell.grupImage.image = array[indexPath.row]["groupImage"] as? UIImage
            cell.grupName.text = array[indexPath.row]["groupname"] as? String
            return cell
        }else{
            
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TownTalkTableViewCell
            cell.grupImage.image = array[indexPath.row]["groupImage"] as? UIImage
            cell.grupName.text = array[indexPath.row]["groupname"] as? String
            return cell
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: please tell me how to set sideMenu tableView header

Comment: `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if tableview == sidemenu {
        return "Header Name"
    }
   
}`

Comment: Do you want multiple section header? can you please describe your problem in spacific

Comment: thanks a lot for the help - I just want to dismiss the sideMenu on click outside from table view, I view didLoad I hide the sideMenu and then true isHidden on click btn --  @IBAction func onClickMenuBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        sideMenu.isHidden = false
        menuView.isHidden = false
        
    }

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have reputation for upvote your answer

Comment: I just want to set the header for the side menu only, not for tableView. please tell me

Comment: can you share an image what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I update the question please check the image output that I want also I want the spacing between the cell rows

Comment: for side menu you can use this pod https://github.com/kukushi/SideMenu or this one https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

Comment: or try this one https://www.appcodezip.com/2020/06/iOS-side-menu-swift.html

Comment: the spacing between the cell rows you can use `tableView.rowHeight = 0` inside cellForRowAt function

Comment: it doesn't work, when I set tableView.rowHeight = 0 - it shows me nothing in tableview

Comment: if tableview == sideMenu{
            // here you use the line and you have to add value not 0. example: tableView.rowHeight =  100 
                                                                                                                                         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TownTalkTableViewCell

Comment: okay, but it doesn't make space between rows

Comment: and please tell me what about the background colour of tableView and and header ?

Answer (score 0):

2 ways.

1. make the view controller data source & delegate for both the tableviews & in the methods add the below check.

   if tableview === self.tableview {
   //its for table view

   return ...
   }
   // else its for side menu

   return ...
2. Create a separate class (Call it SideMenuTableViewHelper or something) for SideMenu tableView datasource & delegate.

First one is simpler, 2nd one is cleaner for datasource, messier for handling delegate (did select row) methods as they will most likely be triggering code in view controller (which can be done via View controller acting as custom delegate to the SideMenuTableViewHelper). For a beginner, I reckon go with (1).